# Pine Script should run as soon as candle close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

im building one strategy, mainly for daily timeframe swing trade. which code i cant show to public as it is private.

my question is, for candles if certain it condition match pine script draw a box on particular signal candle. it work fine in intraday timing as soon as current candle close and next candle open, time difference between them is almost 0 second. so user don't we noticeable difference.

but when it come to daily timeframe after 3:30pm pine code don't run until next day 9:15AM market 1st tick... so user want to plan swing trade has to wait whole market off timing for getting signal candle-drawing. my intention is to get drawing as soon as 1D timeframe candle close, so user can plan his trade list for next day before market open.

### "process_orders_on_close=true" function did not help me as it only fill order as soon as candle close. but all drawing will be drawn on next candle opening.
--demo code--
here code draw box after next candle start to form. i want that box has to be draw as soon as that perticular candle close and before next candle start. becasue as 1D timeframe. next candle start mean we have to wait for 17 hour.

//@version=5
strategy(title="Algo 2.0",overlay=true)

ema50=ta.ema(close,50)
ema200=ta.ema(close,200)

longbuy = strategy.position_size == 0 and ema50>ema200
longstoploss = strategy.position_size > 0 and close<ema200

if longbuy
strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, stop=high, limit=high, qty=2)
box.new(bar_index -1, high , bar_index +1, low, border_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 50), bgcolor = color.rgb(126, 206, 79, 28))

if longstoploss
strategy.exit("SL Hit", from_entry="Enter Long", stop=low)

### plotchar(longbuy, "Go Long",  "▲", location.abovebar, color.rgb(43, 182, 5), size = size.auto)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have added code in main question please check